# Passing a URL with brackets to curl using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, curl, buildkite

I am trying to get the response from a curl url only for a particular value. For example
i am using the command

```
URLS=$(curl -g -H "Authorization: ${abc}" "https://api.buildkite.com/v2/organizations/org/agents?meta_data=[queue=dev]")

echo "${URLS}"
```

The metadata is actually as below:

```
"meta_data": [
      "queue=dev"
    ]
```

The above curl command is giving the response for all agents in all queues and not able to get the required ones specific to queue=dev.

What is the correct way to pass url with brackets?

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation for the [Agents API](https://buildkite.com/docs/apis/rest-api/agents) that suggests you can pass metadata in a query like this.

Comment: Try with \ before each bracket.

Comment: The metadata you show is part of the JSON *response* returned that describes a given agent.

Comment: From online docs. meta_data Filters the results by the given meta_data.
Example: ?meta_data[some-key]=some-value

Comment: Have you tried to use single quotes for the URL (not for the header)?